# Condition variables vs atomic types for synchronization

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, concurrency, atomic

Suppose I have producer and consumer threads synchronized using a condition variable.

```
// Approach 1 - Using condition variable
mutex mmutex;
condition_variable mcond;
queue<string> mqueue;

void producer(){
    while (true) {
        unique_lock<mutex> lck(mmutex);
        mqueue.push_back("Hello Hi");
        mcond.notify_one();
    }
}

void consumer{
    while (true){
        unique_lock<mutex> lck(mmutex); // locks mmutex
        mcond.wait(); // releases mmutex;
        string s = mqueue.front(); // locks mmutex again
        mqueue.pop();
        mmutex.unlock();
    }
}
```

How does the above code compare for synchronization using simple atomic types, as follows -

```
// Approach 2 - using atomics
atomic_bool condition = false;
condition_variable mcond;
queue<string> mqueue;

void producer(){
    unique_lock<mutex> lck(mmutex);
    mqueue.push_back("Hello Hi");
    condition = true;
}

void consumer{
    while (1) {
        if (condition == true) {
            condition = false;
            unique_lock<mutex> lck(mmutex);
            mqueue.front();
            mqueue.pop();
            lck.unlock();
        }
    }
}
```

Since, condition variables exist, I assume they are the preferred means of achieving synchronization in cases like these. If indeed so, why are condition variables a better alternative to the simple atomic_bool (or atomic_int if you need more then two states) based synchronization? If not, then what is the best way to achieve synchronization in this case?

Comment: `wait` needs to be called with the lock. And you need to handle spurious wakeup.

Comment: @T.C. Are you sure about the wait needing to be called with lock in consumer? I was copied code from Tour of C++ by Bjarne Stroustrup.

Comment: You're aware that neither of your solutions works if the producer is faster than the consumer? The condition variable solution also doesn't handle spurious wake-ups.

Comment: @Voo Thanks. I'm reading about spurious wakes. Yes, I'm aware that my code will fail if producer is faster than consume

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The difference is that a condition variable doesn't consume CPU cycles while another thread is waiting for it. If you use an atomic variable for synchronization you have to keep checking its value in a loop.

Comment: If you have a multicore processor, does using condition variables still result in performance boost over the other approach?

Comment: @FirstJens - yes, that's what they're designed for. If you have a thread sitting in a tight loop waiting for an atomic variable to get a specific value you're eating CPU cycles, regardless of how many processors you have.

Comment: Busy waiting _may_ be faster than using condition variable in special cases. If your entire application runs 2 threads on 2 CPUs (specifically, your grant a dedicated CPU for the consumer thread) with no contention with other applications, then busy waiting may do faster data transfer between threads. Condition variables do extra work in both your threads, e.g. switching to/from kernel, which isn't quite cheap. In multitasking environments wasting CPU for busy waiting is unacceptable usually.

Comment: which is also why we have yield. `while(!ready){std::this_thread::yield();}`

Comment: Is this answer still true, considering that `atomic_wait` exists?